# Angular abstract singleton service

Tags: angular, singleton

For testing purposes I create abstract service to easy switch production/mockup services. However I discover that `providedIn: 'root'` not working as expected (many service istances are created). Here is abstract class

```js
@Injectable({providedIn: 'root',})
export abstract class AbstractAuthService {
  abstract loadUserProfile(): Observable<UserProfile>;
  ...
}
```

here is its implementation

```js
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class AuthService implements AbstractAuthService {
  time = 0;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    // code for detect how many instances are created
    this.time = +new Date();
    console.log('CONSTURCTOR', this.time);
  }
  
  loadUserProfile() { console.log('load profile', this.time); ... }

  ...
}
```

and in app.module.ts

```js
@NgModule({
  ...
  providers: [
    { provide: AbstractAuthService, useClass: AuthService }
    ...
  ],
  ...
```

For this code, when I run it in browser (and call method `loadUserProfile` in few places) I see

```
> CONSTURCTOR 1623167229573
> ...
> CONSTURCTOR 1623167229612
> ...
> load profile 1623167229573
> load profile 1623167229612
> load profile 1623167229573
> load profile 1623167229612
> ...
```

This means that angular create at lest two instances of this service and runs them alternately for each `loadUserProfile` call. I want create only one - singleton - because I save csrfToken and other auth data on that service.

**How to do it?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found following solution which is simple but 'low readable' - in app.module.ts use `useExisting` instead of `useClass`

```js
{ provide: AbstractAuthService, useExisting: AuthService }
```